# Convert Points to Polygon using PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I want to create a polygon table using PostGIS. Each row in table '`point`' has three-point `ID.`
Table '`point_location`' has the location information of points. I googled this question but did not find the answer. What's wrong with the following code?

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || b.x || ' ' || b.y || ',' || c.x || ' ' || c.y || ',' || d.x || ' ' || d.y || ',' || b.x || ' ' || b.y'))',4326) 
AS polygon
FROM point a, point_location b, point_location c, point_location d
WHERE a.p1=b.point_id AND a.p2=c.point_id AND a.p3=d.point_id
```

Comment: You should ask this question in gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A better way to construct a polygon from points is to use [PostGIS' geometry constructors](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors). This way, you avoid the need to convert binary → text → binary ([WKB → WKT → WKB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)), which is slower, lossy, and is prone to text formatting distractions as evidenced by the missing `||`. For example, try:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[b, c, d, b]))
FROM point a, point_location b, point_location c, point_location d
WHERE a.p1=b.point_id and a.p2=c.point_id and a.p3=d.point_id
```

Comment: Good! This function is better. Thanks.